# Calculating length of lines using PostGIS?

Tags: postgis

I have a set of lines in a table, I want to calculate the length of each line in kilometers and add is a new column in the table. How would I do this?

my table has been set up as

```
CREATE TABLE public.line (id integer Not Null, 
                          name VARCHAR (25), 
                          geom geometry (LineString, 27700));
```

when I try to calculate the distance of the line in km I get an error message saying only lon/lat coordinate systems are supported in geography. how do I fix this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can add the column

```
ALTER mytable ADD COLUMN (roadlength real);
```

Then you use [`ST_LENGTH`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Length.html) to update it. Here I will convert it to geography first to get the results in meters, then convert to km.

```
UPDATE mytable 
SET roadlength = ST_LENGTH(geom::geography) / 1000;
```

Since your projection unit is already in meters, ignoring any potential projection distortion, you can directly use the geometry.

```
UPDATE mytable 
SET roadlength = ST_LENGTH(geom) / 1000;
```